# Magento Mage_Core_Block_Template assign()

Tags: magento

When would it be advisable to use assign() vs setData()

I can see limited use of assign in the core code base but its not clear when to prefer this use over simple setData

Is this feature deprecated or is there a specific purpose for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT there is no clear precedent for its usage.

Values which are `assign()`ed are stored in `_viewVars` array and `extract()`ed to local scope in `Mage_Core_Block_Template::fetchView()`; use that how you will.

Comment: Just have to put it down to another wierdism in magento.  I am finding a lot of little features like this that dont make 100% sense.  Maybe things that got added to the code base but developers changing minds and not removing?

Comment: `Mage_Core_Block_Flush`, using `parent="block_name"` or `json="{{some:json}}"` in layout XML, etc... Magento is replete with functionality which is never used anywhere. "Magento is a graveyard of good ideas" was the best way I've heard it described. :-)

Comment: This only makes it more difficult for new developers to learn 'the best way' to do things unfortunately

Comment: There's often more than one best way. As my buddy Vinai says, "Magento is all about options" (always said with a wry smile)...